# Asp.Net Mvc Html.BeginFormSubmit ajax sends twice request (one's type xhr the other's document)

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, http-post, html.beginform

I am working on a survey application with Asp.Net MVC. I have a page named Index.cshtml which has a question table and a 'Add New' button.Once button clicked, a popup is opened with jQuery. I am calling a view from controller to fill jQuery dialog named as AddOrEdit.cshtml (child page). I am adding new question and options. Question is a textfield and its options are added in editable table. Once clicked submt button Submit form event (save or update) is fired. But ajax sends twice request. One of these requests send empty object, the other sends full object. Where am I making a mistake?

According to my research, what causes this problem is that the unobtrusive validator is placed on 2 different pages. But this is not the case for me.

When I debug with chrome in f12, the initiator of one of the 2 requests 'jquery' the initiator of the other 'other' The type of one of these 2 post requests appears as 'XHR' and the type of the other is 'document'.

**Index.cshtml**

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Soru Listesi";
}

<h2>Soru Oluşturma</h2>
<a class="btn btn-success" style="margin-bottom: 10px" 
onclick="PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit","Question")')"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Yeni Soru Oluştur</a><table id="questionTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered accent-blue" style="width: 100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Soru No</th>
        <th>Soru Adı</th>
        <th>Oluşturma Tarihi</th>
        <th>Güncelleme Tarihi</th>
        <th>Güncelle/Sil</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
</table>
<link 
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" 
rel="stylesheet" />



 @section Scripts{
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.20/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js"></script>

<script>


    var Popup, dataTable;
    $(document).ready(function() {

        dataTable = $("#questionTable").DataTable({
            "ajax": {
                "url": "/Question/GetData",
                "type": "GET",
                "datatype": "json"
            },
            "columnDefs": [
                { targets: 2 }
            ],
            "scrollX": true,
            "scrollY": "auto",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "QuestionId" },
                { "data": "QuestionName" },
                {
                    "data": "CreatedDate",
                    "render": function(data) { return getDateString(data); }
                },
                {
                    "data": "UpdatedDate",
                    "render": function(data) { return getDateString(data); }
                },
                {
                    "data": "QuestionId",
                    "render": function(data) {
                        return "<a class='btn btn-primary btn-sm' onclick=PopupForm('@Url.Action("AddOrEdit", "Question")/" +
                            data +
                            "')><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i> Güncelle</a><a class='btn btn-danger btn-sm' style='margin-left:5px' onclick=Delete(" +
                            data +
                            ")><i class='fa fa-trash'></i> Sil</a>";
                    },
                    "orderable": false,
                    "searchable": false,
                    "width": "150px"
                }
            ],
            "language": {
                "emptyTable":
                    "Soru bulunamadı, lütfen <b>Yeni Soru Oluştur</b> butonuna tıklayarak yeni soru oluşturunuz. "
            }
        });
    });


    function getDateString(date) {
        var dateObj = new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
        let year = dateObj.getFullYear();
        let month = (1 + dateObj.getMonth()).toString().padStart(2, '0');
        let day = dateObj.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0');
        return day + '/' + month + '/' + year;
    };


    function PopupForm(url) {
        var formDiv = $('<div/>');
        $.get(url)
            .done(function(response) {
                formDiv.html(response);
                Popup = formDiv.dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    title: 'Soru Detay',
                    modal: true,
                    height: 'auto',
                    width: '700',
                    close: function() {
                        Popup.dialog('destroy').remove();
                    }

                });
            });
    }

    function SubmitForm(form) {
        debugger;
        if (form.checkValidity() === false) {
            debugger;
            event.preventDefault();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
        form.classList.add('was-validated');
        if ($(form).valid()) {
            var question = {};
            question.questionId = 1111;
            var options = new Array();
            $("#questionForm TBODY TR").each(function() {
                var row = $(this);
                var option = {};
                option.OptionId = row.find("TD").eq(0).html();
                option.OptionName = row.find("TD").eq(1).html();
                options.push(option);
            });
            question.options = options;
            question.responses = new Array();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: form.action,
                data: JSON.stringify(question),
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        debugger;
                        Popup.dialog('close');
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                        $.notify(data.message,
                            {
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                className: "success",
                                showAnimation: "slideDown",
                                gap: 1000
                            });
                    }
                },
                error: function(req, err) {
                    debugger;
                    alert('req : ' + req + ' err : ' + err.data);
                },
                complete: function(data) {
                    alert('complete : ' + data.status);
                }
            });
        }
    }


    function ResetForm(form) {
        Popup.dialog('close');
        return false;
    }

    function Delete(id) {
        if (confirm('Bu soruyu silmek istediğinizden emin misiniz?')) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("Delete", "Question")/' + id,
                success: function(data) {
                    if (data.success) {
                        dataTable.ajax.reload();
                        $.notify(data.message,
                            {
                                className: "success",
                                globalPosition: "top center",
                                title: "BAŞARILI"
                            })
                    }
                }

            });
        }
    }

</script>
}
```

**AddOrEdit.cshtml**

```
@using MerinosSurvey.Models
@model Questions
@{
Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("AddOrEdit", "Question", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "needs-validation", 
novalidate = "true", onsubmit = "return SubmitForm(this)", onreset = "return ResetForm(this)", id = 
"questionForm" }))
{
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.Label("QuestionId", "Soru No", new { @class = "col-form-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.QuestionId, new { @readonly = "readonly", @class = "form-control" })

    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group row">
    @Html.Label("QuestionName", "Soru Adı", new { @class = "col-form-label col-md-3" })
    <div class="col-md-9">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.QuestionName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", required = "true" } })
        <div class="valid-feedback"><i class="fa fa-check">Süpersin</i></div>
        <div class="invalid-feedback "><i class="fa fa-times"></i></div>
    </div>
</div>


@*<div class="form-group row">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CreatedDate, new { @class = "form-control-label col-md-3"})
        <div class="col-md-9">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CreatedDate, "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", type = "date", @readonly = "readonly",required="false" } })

        </div>
    </div>*@


<div class="table-wrapper form-group table-responsive-md">
    <div class="table-title">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-md-9">Seçenekler</div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <a class="btn btn-success add-new" style="margin-bottom: 10px"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i>Seçenek Ekle</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table optionTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col">Seçenek Id</th>
                <th scope="col">Seçenek Adı</th>
                <th scope="col">Güncelle/Sil</th>
            </tr>

        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @*@foreach (Options options in Model.Options)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@options.OptionId</td>
                        <td>@options.OptionName</td>
                        <td>
                            <a class="add btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"> 
<i class="fa fa-check">Onayla</i></a>
                            <a class="edit btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-pencil">Güncelle</i></a>
                            <a class="delete btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-trash">Sil</i></a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }*@
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="form-group row">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="btnSubmit" />
    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn btn-secondary" />
</div>
}
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
     //var actions = $("table.optionTable td:last-child").html();

     var actions =' <a class="add btn btn-primary btn-sm" title="Add" data-toggle="tooltip"><i 
    class="fa fa-check">Onayla</i></a>' + '<a class="edit btn btn-secondary btn-sm" title="Edit" data toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-pencil">Güncelle</i></a>' +'<a class="delete btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" data-toggle="tooltip"><i class="fa fa-trash">Sil</i></a>';

    // Append table with add row form on add new button click
    $(".add-new").click(function () {
        $(this).attr("disabled", "disabled");
        var index = $("table.optionTable tbody tr:last-child").index();
        var row = '<tr>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="optionId" id="optionId"></td>' +
            '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="optionId" id="optionName"></td>' +
            '<td>' + actions + '</td>' +
        '</tr>';
        $("table.optionTable").append(row);
        $("table.optionTable tbody tr").eq(index + 1).find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });



    // Add row on add button click
    $(document).on("click", ".add", function () {
        var empty = false;
        var input = $(this).parents("tr").find('input[type="text"]');
        input.each(function () {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
                $(this).addClass("error");
                empty = true;
            } else {
                $(this).removeClass("error");
            }
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".error").first().focus();
        if (!empty) {
            input.each(function () {
                $(this).parent("td").html($(this).val());
            });
            $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
            $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
    });

    // Edit row on edit button click
    $(document).on("click", ".edit", function () {

        $(this).parents("tr").find("td:not(:last-child)").each(function () {
            $(this).html('<input type="text" class="form-control" value="' + $(this).text() + '">');
        });
        $(this).parents("tr").find(".add, .edit").toggle();
        $(".add-new").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    });



    // Delete row on delete button click
    $(document).on("click", ".delete", function () {
        debugger;
        $(this).parents("tr").remove();
        $(".add-new").removeAttr("disabled");
    });
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Asp.Net Mvc Html.BeginFormSubmit ajax send twice request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59489482/asp-net-mvc-html-beginformsubmit-ajax-send-twice-request)

Comment: @RajeshG no unfortunately there was no change. I've been dealing with this for two days. I can not move forward.Please help me to solve it

Comment: why not use Ajax form instead of regular form?

Comment: I wonder what you call ajax form. Because my page is very similar to this page, that's how it works. I'm a java developer. I'm developing a project for the first time in Asp.Net.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I am under a tight deadline [of 02.01.2019]

Comment: Join the [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204937/room-for-rajesh-g-and-user6172721)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

event.preventDefault(); move this line and place it immediately after function SubmitForm (form){

Like below:

```
function SubmitForm(form) { 
    debugger; 
event.preventDefault(); 
if (form.checkValidity() === false) { 
debugger; 

event.stopPropagation(); 
} 
form.classList.add('was-validated'); 
if ($(form).valid()) { 
var question = {}; 
question.questionId = 1111; 
var options = new Array(); 
$("#questionForm TBODY TR").each(function() { 
var row = $(this); 
var option = {}; 
option.OptionId = row.find("TD").eq(0).html(); 
option.OptionName = row.find("TD").eq(1).html(); 
options.push(option); 
}); 
question.options = options; 
question.responses = new Array(); 
$.ajax({ 
type: "POST", 
url: form.action, 
data: JSON.stringify(question), 
success: function(data) { 
if (data.success) { 
debugger; 
Popup.dialog('close'); 
dataTable.ajax.reload(); 
$.notify(data.message, 
{ 
globalPosition: "top center", 
className: "success", 
showAnimation: "slideDown", 
gap: 1000 
}); 
} 
}, 
error: function(req, err) { 
debugger; 
alert('req : ' + req + ' err : ' + err.data); 
}, 
complete: function(data) { 
alert('complete : ' + data.status); 
} 
}); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much my brother your help.I worked fine